# How to write $v^T(ZZ^T \odot M)u$ as a product of two numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Z\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times 1}$. Denote $\odot$ as the Hadamard product for matrices. And $M\in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ where $M_{ij} = m_{ij}$. In the following, we let $p=2$ for simplicity.

If we don't have the term $ \odot M$, then it is clear that $v^TZZ^Tu = (v^TZ)(Z^Tu)$, which is a product of two values.

My question is, is it possible to rewrite $v^T(ZZ^T \odot M)u$ as $v^TXX^Tu$ for some vector $X$? If not, is it at least possible to rewrite it as $v^TXY^Tu$ for some vectors $X$, $Y$? Please note that $X,Y$ must not depend on $u$ or $v$, but they can depend on entries of $Z$ and $M$.

This is what I have tried on rewriting $v^T(ZZ^T \odot M)u$:

$$
v^T\left(\begin{array}{ll} 
z_1 z_1m_{11} & z_1 z_2m_{12} \\
z_2 z_1m_{21} & z_2 z_2m_{22}
\end{array}\right)u
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& =z_1 z_1m_{11}v^T\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)u+ 
z_1 z_2m_{12}v^T\left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)u+ \\
&z_2 z_1m_{21}v^T\left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)u + 
z_2 z_2m_{22}v^T\left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)u \\
& =z_1 z_1m_{11}v^Te_1e_1^Tu+ 
 z_1 z_2m_{12}v^Te_1e_2^Tu+ 
z_2 z_1m_{21}v^Te_2e_1^Tu+
z_2 z_2m_{22}v^Te_2e_2^Tu
\end{aligned}
$$

which is a sum of values, where each summand is a product of values.

But I'm wondering if there is a more compact way of re-expressing $v^T(ZZ^T \odot M)u$.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I edited my question to make it more clear. Thank you!

Comment: My original problem is actually element-wise division.. But for sure I can change my problem statement here.

Comment: Ah, yes sorry, didn't pay attention to the definition of $M$. In the $2\times2$ case, by matching coefficients and multiplying diagonal elements (and antidiagonals), I find that $|M|=0$, so it doesn't seem possible in all cases (there may be other constraints).

Comment: Got it. Thank you for trying!

Comment: You can prove, for vectors $A,B,C,D$: $(AB^T)\odot(CD^T)=(A\odot C)(B\odot D)^T$. Therefore, **if $M$ has rank $1$**, you can write $M=\mu\nu^T$ and $(ZZ^T)\odot M=(ZZ^T)\odot (\mu\nu^T)=(Z\odot \mu)(Z\odot \nu)^T=XY^T$ with $X=Z\odot\mu$ and $Y=Z\odot\nu$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you so much. I actually did manage to write $M$ as a sum of two matrices, one is rank one, and one is diagonal.